RadioButton и Вывод
Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите новичку. После выполнения запроса к базе, мы получаем значение времени. Далее у нас формируются группы кнопок и выводятся на форму. На кнопках отображается значение времени и вот если оно совпадает, то кнопка должна быть не активной, а если нету значений времени, то кнопки просто активны. На данный момент работает, так что если записей вообще нету то все группы кнопок все активны (так и должно быть), а вот если есть запись хотя бы одна, то все группы кнопок не активны (так быть не должно), вопрос в том как мне переделать условие или сравнение значений из базы со значениями кнопок.


<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['name2'])) {
        $adress_record = $_POST['adress1'];
        $date_record = $_POST['date1'];
        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT time_record FROM order_record WHERE adress_record=:adress1 and date_record=:date1 ORDER BY `order_record`.`time_record` ASC");
        $query->bindParam("adress1", $adress_record, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("date1", $date_record, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {   //Думаю, что тут надо изменить условие, если уже есть записи в базе
        $disabledAttr = ' disabled="disabled"';
    $htmlContent = <<<HTML
    <br>
    <span style="color: black; align: left;">Выберите свободное время визита</span>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Базовая группа переключателей радио">
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" value="09-00"  autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">09-00</label>
 
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" value="09-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">09-30</label>
 
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" value="10-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">10-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio4" value="10-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio4">10-30</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio5" value="11-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio5">11-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio6" value="11-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio6">11-30</label>
</div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Базовая группа переключателей радио">
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio7" value="12-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio7">12-00</label>
 
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio8" value="12-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio8">12-30</label>
 
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio9" value="13-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio9">13-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio10" value="13-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio10">13-30</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio11" value="14-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio11">14-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio12" value="14-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio12">14-30</label>
</div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Базовая группа переключателей радио">
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio13" value="15-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio13">15-00</label>
 
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio14" value="15-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio14">15-30</label>
 
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio15" value="16-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio15">16-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio16" value="16-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio16">16-30</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio17" value="17-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio17">17-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio18" value="17-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio18">17-30</label>
</div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Базовая группа переключателей радио">
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio19" value="18-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio19">18-00</label>
 
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio20" value="18-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio20">18-30</label>
 
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio21" value="19-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio21">19-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio22" value="19-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio22">19-30</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio23" value="20-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio23">20-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" ' . $disabledAttr . ' class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio24" value="20-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio24">20-30</label>
</div>
HTML;   
  echo $htmlContent;    
    } else {
        $disabledAttr = '';
    }
        if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
                $htmlContent = <<<HTML
    <br>
    <span style="color: black; align: left;">Выберите свободное время визита</span>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Базовая группа переключателей радио">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" value="09-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">09-00</label>
 
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" value="09-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">09-30</label>
 
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" value="10-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">10-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio4" value="10-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio4">10-30</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio5" value="11-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio5">11-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio6" value="11-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio6">11-30</label>
</div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Базовая группа переключателей радио">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio7" value="12-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio7">12-00</label>
 
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio8" value="12-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio8">12-30</label>
 
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio9" value="13-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio9">13-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio10" value="13-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio10">13-30</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio11" value="14-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio11">14-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio12" value="14-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio12">14-30</label>
</div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Базовая группа переключателей радио">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio13" value="15-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio13">15-00</label>
 
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio14" value="15-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio14">15-30</label>
 
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio15" value="16-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio15">16-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio16" value="16-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio16">16-30</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio17" value="17-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio17">17-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio18" value="17-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio18">17-30</label>
</div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Базовая группа переключателей радио">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio19" value="18-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio19">18-00</label>
 
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio20" value="18-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio20">18-30</label>
 
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio21" value="19-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio21">19-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio22" value="19-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio22">19-30</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio23" value="20-00" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio23">20-00</label>
  
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio24" value="20-30" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio24">20-30</label>
</div>
HTML;      
  echo $htmlContent;
            }
        }       
    
?>




добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Вопрос решен. Система записи на прием работает.

отметь данный вопрос как принят )
